# Does using POST vs GET for AJAX affect whether or not Google sees the loaded content?

Tags: ajax, google-cache

I have a site that shows some content of its pages using AJAX with a POST method.

Google is supposed crawls AJAX content for these pages, but when 
I try to make "Fetch as Google" on Google webmaster tools or to see the cached version of my pages on Google, the page shows without the AJAX content.

1. Does it make any difference for Ajax method to be POST or GET?
2. Is there any special treatment I have to do to get Google to crawl the AJAX content as it doesn't show now in the cached version and in Fetch As Google?

Comment: I'm using the .load function in a Ajax and Google sees the content in fetch and render and mobile friendly test. You can try that. Or maybe there's something on your page or robots file preventing Google from accessing it

Comment: I also think it is much more likely to be robots.txt related rather than POST vs GET, but I don't have a lot of experience getting AJAX content indexed, so I don't know for sure.